# "sudo apt-get remove hadoop" is not removing package

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apt, hadoop, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall Cloudera Hadoop from my Ubuntu System. For this I tried `sudo apt-get remove hadoop` command but this command is failing with following message:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-82-19-71:~/cluster-deployer/src$ sudo apt-get remove hadoop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package hadoop is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hadoop-hdfs-datanode : Depends: hadoop-hdfs (= 2.5.0+cdh5.3.0+781-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.54~precise-cdh5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 hadoop-hdfs-namenode : Depends: hadoop-hdfs (= 2.5.0+cdh5.3.0+781-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.54~precise-cdh5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 hadoop-yarn-nodemanager : Depends: hadoop-yarn (= 2.5.0+cdh5.3.0+781-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.54~precise-cdh5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager : Depends: hadoop-yarn (= 2.5.0+cdh5.3.0+781-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.54~precise-cdh5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Initially this command was not working so I killed one `yarn` process usking `kill -9 <pid>` and then executed above command but now I am not able to uninstall anything nor I am able to remove anything :(

What should I do next?

Comment: try apt-get autoremove

Comment: Hi, just now I tried 'apt-get autoremove' and 'apt-get check' also but I am getting same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed this completely. I had answer just in front of me. `sudo apt-get update` command solved this problem. and this trick is given in the output of `sudo apt-get remove hadoop` command itself (in the last line)

Sorry for the trouble caused and thanks a lot for your quick answers :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `hadoop` package is not installed *with APT*: "Package hadoop is not installed, so not removed". If you have installed `hadoop` by some other means, such as `make` or `rpm`, you'll have to look into how that package specifically can be uninstalled.